# How do I conditionally connect one gui to another?

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface, tkinter, network-programming

This is my first time experimenting with both GUIs and client-server applications so I am struggling. I (hopefully) have a server side and client side and a gui to prompt the user for their username and password (which is stored in a text document on the server side).  The gui (sort of) works on the client side, but upon the successful input of a matching username and password combination, I have no idea how to call a separate 'menu' gui to open.  How do I import menu.py from client.py so that when a user successfully logs in, they are greeted with a separate gui?  The code is below.  Let me know if I'm missing anything. Thanks!

Client:

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
from tkinter import ttk

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

class LoginFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_2 = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command = self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()

    def _login_btn_clicked(self):

        username = self.entry_1.get()
        clientSocket.sendto(username.encode('UTF-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

        password = self.entry_2.get()
        clientSocket.sendto(password.encode('UTF-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

        message, address = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        message = message.decode('UTF-8')

        if message == "200 OK":
            tm.showinfo("Logged in", message)

        else:
            tm.showinfo("Login error", message)

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI")
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(270, 80))
lf = LoginFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Server:

```
import socket
# Create a UDP socket
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Assign IP address and port number to socket
serverSocket.bind(('', 12000))

while True:
    # Receive the client packet along with the address it is coming from
    username, address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)
    username = username.decode('UTF-8')

    password, address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)
    password = password.decode('UTF-8')

    infile = open("sales.txt", 'r')

    for rows in infile:    #equivalent to: Recs=infile.readline()
                        #this gets 1 line at a time as a string including \n
        rows = rows.strip()
        rowsList = rows.split('\t')
        #message += row + "\n" # + str(rowsList)
        username2 = rowsList[0].strip(' ')
        if username == username2:

            password2 = rowsList[1]
            if password == password2:

                # the server responds
                message = "200 OK"
                message = message.encode('UTF-8')
                serverSocket.sendto(message, address)

            else:
                # the server responds
                message = "401 Unauthorized"
                message = message.encode('UTF-8')
                serverSocket.sendto(message, address)

    # the server responds
    message = "401 Unauthorized"
    message = message.encode('UTF-8')
    serverSocket.sendto(message, address)
    infile.close()
```

Menu:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MenuFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
        mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        name = "John"
        sales = StringVar()
        moreSales = StringVar()
        sales.set("1")

        welcome = "Welcome, " + name + "!"

        sales_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = moreSales)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = welcome).grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = W)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Current Sales:").grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = sales).grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = (E))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "sales").grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = W)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Add Sales").grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = W)
        sales_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (W, E))
        ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Add", command = MenuFrame.add(sales, moreSales)).grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = W)

        ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Log Out", command = MenuFrame.logout).grid(column = 2, row = 4, sticky = W)

    def add(sales, moreSales):

        try:
            value1 = int(sales.get())
            value2 = int(moreSales.get())
            sales.set(value1 + value2)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def logout():
        root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI")
mf = MenuFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: I tried

```
import Menu
```

and added

```
    root = Tk()
    root.title("GUI")
    mf = MenuFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

after

```
if message == "200 OK" in client.py
```

but I get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Pat\Desktop\DunderMifflinSales-master\DunderMifflinClient.py", line 49, in _login_btn_clicked
    mf = MenuFrame(root)
NameError: name 'MenuFrame' is not defined
```

Comment: You would have to do `Menu.MenuFrame` because you haven't done a wild import.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I figured that part out and I now get access to both GUIs but not at all in the order that I would expect.

Comment: this is a poorly worded question. There's way more code than is necessary to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to make sure this second GUI is properly importable. There must be no code that actually creates a window in the global scope of the module. You need to completely remove this block of code from `Menu.py`:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI")
mf = MenuFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Once you've done that, your code should work fine. Assuming you want the code in "Menu.py" to appear in a separate window you would do something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import Menu
...
if should_display_new_gui:
    toplevel = Toplevel(root)
    mf = Menu.MenuFrame(toplevel)
    mf.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

If you want the menu frame to appear in the same root window rather than a new window, you can skip creating an instance of `Toplevel` and instead pass in `root` as the parameter to `MenuFrame`.

You have other bugs in your `MenuFrame` code which are unrelated to this specific problem. For example, consider this code:

```
ttk.Button(..., command = MenuFrame.add(...)).grid(...)
```

The first problem is that `MenuFrame` is a class, and `add` is a method of an *instance* of the class. So, the first thing that needs to be fixed is to use `self.add(...)` rather than `MenuFrame.add(...)`.

The second problem is that when you do `..., command=add(...)`, this _immediately calls `add` and assigns the result to `command`. It's no different than if you did this:

```
cmd = MenuFrame.add(...)
ttk.Button(..., command = cmd).grid(...)
```

You need to pass `command` a *reference* to a function, not the function itself. If you are passing variables you would typically use `lambda` or `functools.partial`. However, you don't need to be passing anything in because your `add` method is fetching the data it needs. So, you can change the command to be simply:

```
ttk.Button(..., command=self.add).grid(...)
```

Then, define `add` like this:

```
def add(self):
    value1 = int(sales.get())
    value2 = int(moreSales.get())
```

**However**, that won't work because `sales` and `moreSales` are local variables. You need to save them as attributes of the class:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
    ...
    self.sales = StringVar()
    self.moreSales = StringVar()
    ...
```

And then you can access them like this:

```
def add(self):
    value1 = int(self.sales.get())
    value2 = int(self.moreSales.get())
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much.  This was incredibly helpful!  Thanks for answering even though the question wasn't well-worded